# Get XML from XPathDocument

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xslt

I am working on a stylesheet and have some initial XML. However the XML is being manipulated a bit before styling and i would like to get the final XML sent into `.Transform()`. For instance, ...

```
XslCompiledTransform.Transform( xpd, xslArg, output )
```

...i would like to get the Xml content of xpd (as a string), so i can work on the stylesheet in other tools.

Is there a quick-and-dirty way to get this? Either in the VS2010 immediate window or as a quick C# line or two before the call to `.Transform()`?

EDIT: The `.Transform()` i'm using is

```
public void Transform(IXPathNavigable input,
   XsltArgumentList arguments, TextWriter results);
```

...and `xpd` is an `XPathDocument`.

Comment: Did you try `ToString()` ?

Comment: Which overload of `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` are you using?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - yep. "System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument"

Comment: @RyanGates - Good question. `public void Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, TextWriter results)` i'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I misunderstood the intent of your question. The simple answer is to get the XML for any IXPathNavigable (which includes XPathDocument), you can do this:

```
string xml = xpd.CreateNavigator().OuterXml;
```

Below is my original answer, which explains how you could modify the XML from an XPathDocument in code before feeding it into a transform:

If `xpd` is an XPathDocument, you might be able to just get an XPathNavigator from the XPathDocument:

```
XPathNavigator xpn = xpd.CreateNavigator();
```

and use that to modify the XML.  When you're done modifying it, you can just pass either `xpn` or `xpd` into the `Transform()` method. On the other hand, MSDN says that XPathDocument's `CreateNavigator()` creates a readonly navigator, so that may be a bit of a hitch.

If it really is readonly, you should be able to do this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xpd.CreateNavigator().OuterXml);
```

then use `doc` to modify the XML and pass `doc` into the transform when you're done.

Comment: i must have been a little unclear. I just want the xml string on the clipboard to more easily work on the Xslt in an external tool. However, i just added `string x = xDoc.CreateNavigator().OuterXml;` and grabbed the value of `x` in the immediate window. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: I see.  So it sounds like I misunderstood what you were looking for, but did indirectly answer your question.  If so, could you mark this as the answer?

Comment: Right. Plussed it up. Will mark it soon if nothing better comes along. :)